# How to segment objects in unsupervised fashion?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

We have a dataset of images with different items from the hyper markets, at this stage we want to detect those objects without using labelled data (cause that what we are trying to avoid).

For instance we have this image:

[image]

and we would like to detect those store items (bounding boxes preferred)
[image]
I've just drawn it around 3 items to convey my point but in the solution it would apply to all the items.

**What we have tried:**

> K means clustering (but the main issue is finding k), we don't know how many items there are )

> Otsu Image thresholding (but the objects have different colors, both dark and light, so the thresholding takes away one or the other) + the objects have hollow parts inside it like the bottle handles.

**What we would like to have:**

> We would like to any leads on what to do here. This doesn't have to be just code solutions, any topics or ideas that could lead us to the solution would be equally appreciated.

Thank you again